# Button/Text Href link click with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I click on the following using Selenium in python?

```
<a onclick="ClearTrackingCode();" id="ctl00_phMainContent_CampaignGrid_grid_ctl02_btnSelect" title="Edit the selected campaigns" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$phMainContent$CampaignGrid$grid$ctl02$btnSelect','')">201362</a>
```

I have tried by ID + Name + Xpath

```
//*[@id="ctl00_phMainContent_CampaignGrid_grid_ctl02_btnSelect"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
execute_script
```

fixed the issue.

execute_script(script, *args)
Synchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame.

Args :
script: The JavaScript to execute.
*args: Any applicable arguments for your JavaScript.
Usage : 
driver.execute_script(‘document.title’)